# how to remain the count down time not beginning at first each time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(function() {
    var count = 20;
    countdown = setInterval(function() {
        $("p.countdown").html(count + "seconds remailing!");

        if (count == 0) {
            window.location = 'http://stackoverflow.com/';
        }

        count--;
    }, 1000);
});​

<p class="countdown">
```

Each time when i refresh the browser, the count down is beginning at 20. i want to when i refresh the browser. the count number not beginning at 20 each time. it begins from the actually time it beginning, how to do some changes to the code?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best method would be to store the current time in a cookie (or some other local storage), and check for it on page load. If it's present, use it. If it's not, start from 20.

To avoid the complexities of managing cross-browser storage, you could use [`amplify.store`](http://amplifyjs.com/api/store/). Simply update the value with each iteration of your interval.

Setting values is pretty trivial:

```
amplify.store( 'countdown', count );
```

As is getting them at a later time:

```
amplify.store( 'countdown' );
```

Your code would look something like this:

```
$(function() {
    // Pick up where we left off, or start from 20
    var count = amplify.store('count') || 20;
    countdown = setInterval(function() {
        $("p.countdown").html(count + " seconds remailing!");
        if (count <= 0) {
            // Clear our stored value
            amplify.store('count', null);
            window.location = 'http://stackoverflow.com/';
        }
        // Update stored value
        amplify.store('count', count--);
    }, 1000);
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yWTR7/ ( Hit 'Run' after a few seconds )

Answer (score 0):

first save time (max time) in php session variable or in datbase, and fire ajax query each 1 second or any interval you like that will decrease the php variable's value. When new page is loaded, load the php variables value in javascript...

**alternative**
You can use cookies to store timer values.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one with localstorage:

```
$(function() {
    var count = localStorage.getItem('count') || 20,
        countdown = setInterval(function() {
            localStorage.setItem('count', count);
            $("p.countdown").html(count + " seconds remaining!");

            if (count === 0) {
                clearInterval(countdown);
                localStorage.removeItem('count');
                window.location = 'http://stackoverflow.com/';
            }

            count--;
        }, 1000);
});
```

​
    ​
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4tj6r/2/)